# Scala: Create a binary Tree from List

Tags: scala, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm a complete beginner in Scala. So my question might be quite stupid, please be patient with me.
I have a template for a binary tree structure:

```
sealed trait Tree[T]
case class Leaf[T]() extends Tree[T]
case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], data :Int, right Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
```

I want to write a function which creates a binary tree from a list. The first list element is the root. All data left of a branch are smaller and all data right of a branch are bigger:

```
def listToTree[T](list: List[T]): Tree[T]
```

I'm not sure what I wrote wrong, but my output is always only the first `List` element

```
def setElement(x: Int, tree: Tree[Int]): Tree[Int] = tree match {
    case Node(l, e, r) => Node(l, x, r)
    case Leaf() => new Node(Leaf(), x, Leaf()) 
}
def listToTree2[T](as: List[Int], tree: Tree[Int], x: Int): Tree[Int] = tree match
{
  case Leaf() => listToTree2(as.tail, setElement(as.head, tree), x)
  case Node(left, e, right) => if(e < x) {
    right match {
      case Leaf() => listToTree2(as.tail, setElement(as.head, tree), x)
      case Node(left2, e2, right2) => if( e < e2) listToTree2(as, right, x)
      else listToTree2(as, left, x)
    }
  } else if(e > x) { 
    left match {
      case Leaf() => listToTree2(as.tail, setElement(as.head, tree), x)
      case Node(left3, e3, right3) => if( e < e3) listToTree2(as, right, x) else listToTree2(as, left, x)
    }
  } else {
    listToTree2(as.tail, tree, x)
  }
}


def listToTree[T](as: List[Int]): Tree[Int] =
{
  val tree = new Node(Leaf(), as.head, Leaf())
  listToTree2(as, tree, as.head)
}
```

So in the end the correct output should be something like this:

```
val list = List(3, 2, 4, 1)
assert(listToTree(list) == Branch(Branch(Branch(Leaf(),1,Leaf()),2,Leaf()))),3,Branch(Leaf(),4,Leaf()))
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things in your code that don't seem to make a lot of sense ... But more importantly, what you have written looks linear to me, and I am pretty sure you can't build a BST in linear time (if you could, you could also sort in linear time then, which would be pretty cool). So, it looks like rather than trying to debug this code, you are better off throwing it out, and rethinking your entire approach.

Immutable structures don't make it particularly easy to implement non-linear things, unfortunately. There are several approaches you could try here. One in particular is borrowing the `partition` idea from the quick sort:

```
def makeTree(data: List[Int]): Tree[Int] = data match {
   case Nil => Leaf()
   case head :: tail => 
      val (left, right) = tail.partition(_ < head)
      Branch(makeTree(left), head, makeTree(right.filterNot(_ == head)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```scala
sealed trait Tree[+T] extends Product with Serializable
final case class Branch[+T](left: Tree[T], elem: T, right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
final case object Leaf extends Tree[Nothing]

object Tree {
  def addToTree[T : Ordering](tree: Tree[T])(t: T): Tree[T] = {
    import Ordering.Implicits._
    
    tree match {
      case Leaf =>
        Branch(left = Leaf, elem = t, right = Leaf)

      case branch @ Branch(left, elem, right) =>
        if (t <= elem) branch.copy(left = addToTree(tree = left)(t))
        else branch.copy(right = addToTree(tree = right)(t))
    }
  }

  def fromList[T : Ordering](data: List[T]): Tree[T] = {    
    data match {
      case root :: tail =>
        tail.foldLeft(Branch(left = Leaf, elem = root, right = Leaf) : Tree[T]) {
          case (acc, t) =>
            addToTree(acc)(t)
        }
      
      case Nil =>
        Leaf
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I divided the problem into multiple steps, first creating a **Tree** from a **List** is basically just starting with a `Branch` that has the root and then start adding each element in the **List** to that base **Tree**.
And adding an element to a **Tree** can also be decomposed into adding it to the `left` or to the `right` accordingly.

---

*You can see the code running in [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/6qLoqaUySGCAOZ5mG5gdqg/9)*.